# Desarrollo de plugin de netbeans: no me aparece la descripción personalizada

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, netbeans-8.2

estaba leyendo [este artículo](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqPluginRequirements) parte de la documentación de NetBeans, con el propósito de agregar una descripción a el plugin que desarrollé con Maven.

Traté de hacer lo que dice sin que aparezca la descripción.

para ello observé que dicho archivo aparecía en otros `nbm`s en la carpeta raíz bajo el directorio Info y en mi maven agregué el archivo en la carpeta Info dentro de recursos.

[image: estructura del proyecto]

Pero a pesar de ello, em complemento aparece sin descripción.

Este es el código del XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Autoupdate Module Info 2.3//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/autoupdate-info-2_3.dtd">
<!--
Copyright (C) 2019 ruslan.lopez
-->

<module codenamebase="org.javapro.regextester"
        distribution="regextester-nb-1.0.2.nbm"
        downloadsize="0"
        homepage="https://github.com/javatlacati/regextester"
        license="gplv3"
        moduleauthor="Ruslan López"
        needsrestart="false"
        releasedate="2018/07/01">
    <manifest
        OpenIDE-Module="org.javapro.regextester"
        OpenIDE-Module-Display-Category="Utilities"
        OpenIDE-Module-Implementation-Version="1.1.0.3"
        OpenIDE-Module-Long-Description="Click the button in your toolbar to see a Regular Expression Utility"
        OpenIDE-Module-Name="Dukescript Java Regex Tester"
        OpenIDE-Module-Requires="org.openide.modules.ModuleFormat1"
        OpenIDE-Module-Short-Description="Click the button in your toolbar to see a Regular Expression Utility"
        OpenIDE-Module-Specification-Version="1.1.0.3"/>
    <license name="gplv3">
<![CDATA[ GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
                       Version 3, 29 June 2007  
    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

Also add information on how to contact you by electronic and paper mail.

  If the program does terminal interaction, make it output a short
notice like this when it starts in an interactive mode:

    <program>  Copyright (C) <year>  <name of author>
    This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `show w'.
    This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
    under certain conditions; type `show c' for details.

The hypothetical commands `show w' and `show c' should show the appropriate
parts of the General Public License.  Of course, your program's commands
might be different; for a GUI interface, you would use an "about box".

  You should also get your employer (if you work as a programmer) or school,
if any, to sign a "copyright disclaimer" for the program, if necessary.
For more information on this, and how to apply and follow the GNU GPL, see
<https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

  The GNU General Public License does not permit incorporating your program
into proprietary programs.  If your program is a subroutine library, you
may consider it more useful to permit linking proprietary applications with
the library.  If this is what you want to do, use the GNU Lesser General
Public License instead of this License.  But first, please read
<https://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-not-lgpl.html>.
]]>

    </license>

</module>
```

[image: plugin listo para instalar aparece sin descripción]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que aparezca algo en descripción de Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar la descripción se debe de hacer en el `pom` mediante la etiqueta `description`, que puede ser tan compleja como se desee.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.javapro</groupId>
    <artifactId>regextester-nb</artifactId>
    <packaging>nbm-application</packaging>
<name>regextester Client for NetBeans</name>
    <description><![CDATA[Click the button in your toolbar to see an Interactive Java regex tester.
        It is currently configured to provide versions for:
        <ul>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>Netbeans Plugin</li>
            <li>IDEA Plugin</li>
            <li>JavaFX jar executable</li>
        </ul>]]></description>
```

En el caso del código anterior producirá la siguiente descripción:

[image: Click the button in your toolbar to see an Interactive Java regex tester.]